# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on AndroidStudio - AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask

I have this method on my `EndpointAsyncTask` in Android:

```
class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<User>> {
private static UserEndpoint myApiService = null;
private Context context;

EndpointsAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

And continues here:

```
@Override
protected List<User> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if(myApiService == null) { // Only do this once
        UserEndpoint.Builder builder = new   UserEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
// options for running against local devappserver
// - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
// - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                .setRootUrl("http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });
// end options for devappserver

        myApiService = builder.build();
    }
```

But this is throwing me an error on `Android Studio 1.2.2` only at runtime btw:

```
9770-9892/com.kkoci.shairlook E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kkoci.shairlook.EndpointsAsyncTask$1
        at com.kkoci.shairlook.EndpointsAsyncTask.doInBackground(EndpointsAsyncTask.java:33)
        at com.kkoci.shairlook.EndpointsAsyncTask.doInBackground(EndpointsAsyncTask.java:22)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
```

I've read somewhere that  `doInBackground` cannot have any `UI` method on it, could it be that?

But really I can't figure it out here, I'm calling this AsyncTask class from an activity, this way:

```
        public void getUSer(View v) {
        new EndpointsAsyncTask(this).execute();
    }
```

This is called from a button, like this:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Register with Twitter"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/twitter_button"
            android:onClick="getUser"/>
```

Any ideas?

Thank in advance!

Comment: It seems class: GoogleClientRequestInitializer not exists. Maybe library is corrupted try to update it.

Comment: Hmmmm okay, should I update it where? On gradle you mean?

Comment: Try to clean project and print more logcat (from all packages) - because the system reports what not found (class or field) and prints it to logcat.

Comment: Ya, tried again, cleaning project but same error, this happens only if I actually press the method button, otherwise compilation goes just fine... How could I update that class? I'm using com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18 , same for endpoints, and endpoints-deps

Comment: Are you checked full logcat maybe problem is with different class or field.

Comment: Yes, found this: '8130-8130/com.kkoci.shairlook E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.kkoci.shairlook.EndpointsAsyncTask$1', referenced from method com.kkoci.shairlook.EndpointsAsyncTask.doInBackground' weird, this isn't an actual 'Activity' though... Maybe Manifest related?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82241/discussion-between-krystian71115-and-neove).

Comment: I'm uploading the classes.dex file

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE178C4025338B36!986&authkey=!AHtlgE9VHZjCqjg&ithint=file%2czip Here it is, thank you very much